# In-place sed command not working

Tags: regex, sed

Using GNU Sed, I always have some sort of trouble with the in-place substitution. In this case, I'm trying to remove some commas from xml entries that look like this:

```
<address>T/A Business Name, 74, Address Line 1, Some Town, Some City</address>
```

...in particular the comma after the address number (e.g. 74) needs to be removed. So I'm using something like this:

```
sed -nr 's!(<address>T/A\s+.*?,\s*[0-9]+\s*),(.*</address>)!\1\2! p'
```

And that prints out the lines that will be changed exactly as I would expect them i.e. the commas after the address numbers are removed. But when I change the command to actually make the changes to the files in-place, like this:

```
sed -ir 's!\(<address>T/A\s+.*?,\s*[0-9]+\s*\),\(.*</address>\)!\1\2!'
```

But the command does nothing. No changes are made but it's the exact same command, except that I had to escape the capture parentheses this time or else I got errors for every matching line like:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 62: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
```

Comment: Depending on your environment, you may have to specify a backup filename after the `-i` option. Check the man page for more info...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try this also,

```
sed -ri 's~^(.*Name, [0-9]+),(.*)$~\1\2~g' file
```

Don't use `-i` before `-r` in sed. If you do so, it displays an error message like above.

**Example:**

```
$ cat aa
<address>T/A Business Name, 74, Address Line 1, Some Town, Some City</address>

$ sed -r 's~^(.*Name, [0-9]+),(.*)$~\1\2~g' aa
<address>T/A Business Name, 74 Address Line 1, Some Town, Some City</address>
```

Comment: Ah, it is, I'm getting duplicate files generated called *.xmlr - I never copped it

Comment: I was just trying to explain **why** it doesn't work if you use `-ir` (i before r)...

Comment: because `r` flag in sed means extended regex which inturn helps to parse the input file. After parsing it, there comes the editing part. So `i` must be preceeded by `r`.

Comment: So just to reiterate, I had to escape the parentheses for the in-place version because I wasn't using any extended regex flag - it was being interpreted as the argument for the -i flag (backup file - which explains all the .xmlr files being generated). Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

For some versions of sed, you need to specify a backup suffix when you use `-i` for in-place editing.

In other versions of sed, the backup suffix is optional.

In your case, the `r` is being interpretted as the backup suffix (because it immediately follows the `i` option).

From the sed man page on my system (Ubuntu 12.04):

```
       -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

          edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

Usage:

```
sed -i.bak "s/this/that/g" input.txt
```

This will cause two things to happen:

1. input.txt will be modified *in-place* by sed
2. input.txt.bak will be created as a backup file