# Replacing a block of text with indents by sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have the next code:

```
echo -e '  aaa\nddd\nddd\n  bbb' | sed -re ':x; N; $!b x; s/(^|\n)(\s*)(aaa)\n(.*?)\n\2(bbb)(\n|$)/\1\2\3\n\2ccc\n\2\5\6/g'
```

That code replaces everything between aaa & bbb with ccc. Also it uses the same indents it finds:

```
fff
   aaa
   ddd
   ddd
   bbb
fff
```

will be processed to

```
fff
   aaa
   ccc
   bbb
fff
```

But there is a problem. I can't port it to use my variables:

```
sed -ire ":x; N; $!b x; s@(^|\n)(\s*)(${START})\n(.*?)\n\2(${STOPSEQREG})(\n|$)@\1\2\3\n\2${ENUMARRAY[$i]}\n\2\5\6@g" $f
```

START, STOPSEQREG & ENUMARRAY[i] contain /, *, spaces, :, ;, + and -. Also the array's elements contain \n. The / & * symbols are escaped with \.

The error it shows when running is "Bad backreference".

Can anyone, please, help me?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Examples of variables:

```
START: /* R+ Testy */ (with escaped / & *)  
STOPSEQREG: /* R- */ (with escaped / & *)   
ENUARRAY[i]: case AAA:\n    break;
```

Comment: can you provide the script in which you use the `sed` with the varible assignments

Comment: Here the full script: http://paste.org.ru/?6iwb4l  
Here is the test files: source: http://paste.org.ru/?yu4yiq and target:  http://paste.org.ru/?tlzelb

Answer (score 1):

A few things I discovered:

- You need to quote the `$`s inside your sed script as BASH will probably get there first and interpret them as empty variables. So instead of `$!b` and `(\n|$)`, try `\$!b` and `(\n|\$)`.
- There is potential for simplifying that regex - e.g. can't `(.*?)` be reduced to `(.+)`?
- ...but most importantly, **don't use `-ire` with (GNU) sed**. The `r` is being consumed as an parameter to `-i` (backup), so your regex is being treated as a basic one, which would need every parenthesis escaped and wouldn't support `\s` etc. This is why sed sees there as being no captured groups. Use `-i -re` instead. See the [GNU SED manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html), and this question too: [In-place sed command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918973/in-place-sed-command-not-working).

*General aside:* for something this complex, I'd personally always look to a language with decent regex and shell support, e.g. Python / Perl / Ruby / Groovy etc. This avoids the BASH (or other shell) / SED quoting <strike>hell</strike> *quirks and issues*, allows unit / integration testing / debugging and logging, but obviously brings its own baggage sometimes, or isn't always possible, unfortunately.

Comment: 1)What should I use instead of -ire?  
2) I've tried to backslash $ symbols or use comething like `; "'$'"!b` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Oops, yeah should probably have added that... see my updated answer! (in short use `-i -re`)

Comment: Here is what code is looks like right now: `sed -i -re ":x; N; \$!b x; s@(^|\n)(\s*)(${START})\n(.+)\n\2(${STOPSEQREG})(\n|\$)@\1\2\3\n\2${ENUMARRAY[$i]}\n\2\5\6@g" $f` But that code doesn't replace anything. The full script: http://paste.org.ru/?6ucf7g

Comment: Well, step one is stop the errors, so that's a good start. Getting the regex right is another problem entirely; what I'd do (other than use another language - see above), is build the regex beforehand to a string, and echo it out to the console. That way, you can use something helpful like www.regexr.com to debug the regex, and test with your input.

BTW, not sure what it's aiming for but I _doubt_ you want that `\2` after the `\n` before the `(${STOPSEQREG})` (on the LHS).

Also, I assume you're UNIX line endings (`\n`) only here, else you need to re-think some stuff.